# Sort table names in Ascending order in SQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sorting

i have a table called Names, where the data is stored like

```
Raju;
Rakesh;
Preema;
Swetha;
+9199869986;
+9145899656;
+9177885555;
Testing;
Doggy;
```

Now, if i need to sort by name, i tried like this

```
"SELECT * FROM namesTable ORDER BY tblNames ASC"
```

Here i'm getting numbers first, i want numbers to be at the end actual letters from A should appear first.

Any help

Comment: why are the numbers in the name field?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: HI, sorry for delay, its sqlite database, suppose user do not have name field stored we will store numbers in names field

Comment: **VERY BAD DESIGN**. Use a default name, instead. Like `No name inserted`.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of string values is based on something called a "collation".  The default collation in your case probably just uses ASCII values, which would put numbers before letters.

You can fix this with `case` logic.  Something like:

```
order by (case when substr(tblNames, 1, 1) in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+') then 2
               else 1
          end),
         tblNames
```

I've made this SQL as generic as possible, because you have tagged the question with two different databases.

Comment: Yes, that should have been `tblNames`.  Your question said "if i need to sort by name", so I just used `name` as the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? It will output the names first? It is not a good idea to have numebers in a column called NAMES

```
 "SELECT * FROM namesTable ORDER BY tblNames DSC"
```